# How do i link my "add to cart" button to a specific on page tab and scroll to it when clicked?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742552/how-to-change-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-based-on-availability) I was trying to create and alternate "add to cart" button on the single-product-page of a Woocommerce website.  Now, I would like that button to link to a tab on the same page, have the page scroll down and switch to that tab when the button is clicked.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr9hj/) is exactly what I need to happen but I do no know how to implement it in the wordpress setting.

So I settled for creating a js script by suggestion of this [place](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-link-to-a-product-tab?replies=18)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( location.href.match(/#tab-reviews/g) !== null ) {
        jQuery( '#tab-reviews' ).show();
        jQuery( 'li.reviews_tab a' ).trigger('click');
    }
</script>
```

Then I called it into word press through the funtion.php file with this, but its not working.

```
function tab_scroll() {
wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/tab_scroll.js', 
    array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tab_scroll' );
```

I dont know if its the way i called the script or just that the script is not written to suit my needs or even written properly

What I would like is some help/suggestions on making the [first](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr9hj/) script work for me. And help on bringing into wordpress.